# I am getting error when trying to connect to MySql using JSP page

Tags: java, jsp, exception

I am unable to connect to MySql using JSP page. This is my connection query -

```
<%
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
Class.forName("Driver").newInstance();
Connection con=null;
ResultSet rst=null;
Statement stmt=null;
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://10.1.11.103:3306/jiradb40","opsrptusr", "opsrptusr");
stmt=con.createStatement();

String query = "(select * from jiraissue limit 2)";
%>
```

I have placed jar file in lib folder still getting the error.

Any help is well appreciated.

---

Exception report

```
 message An exception occurred processing JSP page /Worklog.jsp at line 5

 description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

 exception 
 org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /Worklog.jsp at line 5

2: <%@page import="java.text.DecimalFormat" %>
3:  <%
4: String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
5: Class.forName("Driver").newInstance();
6: Connection con=null;
7: ResultSet rst=null;
8: Statement stmt=null;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect:

```
Class.forName("Driver").newInstance();
```

That's trying to find a class called `Driver` in the default package.

You *potentially* want:

```
Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
```

... but even that shouldn't be required:

- Just using `Class.forName()` should initialize the class, which would then register itself with `DriverManager`
- You don't need to use `Class.forName` anyway now, if you're working with a fairly modern JRE. From the docs for `DriverManager`:

  > Applications no longer need to explictly load JDBC drivers using Class.forName(). Existing programs which currently load JDBC drivers using Class.forName() will continue to work without modification.

Note that as a matter of style, there's no point in declaring variables and giving them an initial value of `null`, only to assign a new value immediately. Just use:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
// ...
```